# why create object without "new" , i think it true that Typeface typeface = new Typeface();?[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9HqN.png

Tags: java

[i don't understand this basic code, hopfully people help me . Thanks a lots][1]

Comment: You're getting negative feedback because this is something you can research yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Constructor and static method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803032/java-constructor-and-static-method)

Comment: Dont post links to external sites containing your code. Most SO users will not even bother to follow that link. Rather paste your code right in the question!

Answer (score 0):

static methods can be called directly via dot(.) operator in java, as createFromAsset is a static method it can be called this way

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/fontName.ttf");
```

Answer (score 0):

`createFromAsset` is an `static` method that's why we don't need to use `new`. We can easily ascess it using `class name` & `dot(.)` operator.

```
public static Typeface createFromAsset(AssetManager mgr, String path) {
    if (sFallbackFonts != null) {
        FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily();
        if (fontFamily.addFontFromAsset(mgr, path)) {
            FontFamily[] families = { fontFamily };
            return createFromFamiliesWithDefault(families);
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Font asset not found " + path);
}
```